# What do you do if you upgrade you bag in Pokémon go and the coins are taken but the bag was not upgraded?

Tags: pokemon-go

What do you do if you upgrade you bag in Pokémon go and the coins are taken but the bag was not upgraded? I bought a $15 iTunes card, redeemed it, bought 1200 Pokémon coins, bought several incubators and a bag upgrade. Everything is there except my "bag" level did not go up. How do I get my coins back or the bag level increasesd?

Comment: This is a question for Niantic not here - we aren't customer support for pokemon-go.

Answer (score 4):

You must ask Niantic for help which can be found on this [support webpage](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222465267-Help-with-Pok%C3%A9Coins-and-premium-items-FAQ).